# Google Sheets confirmation prompt on edit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I've been working on a large Google Sheets project, and I have a column with Yes/No dropdowns. Changing a cell to 'No' will delete a corresponding row in another sheet, so I want to pop up a warning so they can cancel if they didn't realize or it was a misclick.

This is how I was trying to do it:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt("This will delete the corresponding entry in ShinyDex. Continue?",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
if( response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
              removeShinyHunt(row,r);
            } else if(response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
              r.setValue("Yes");
            }
```

Seemed pretty straight forward, but after a lot of hair pulling I realized you can't call prompts in onEdit as it runs in AuthMode.LIMITED. I can't seem to find any way around this, but I want some sort confirmation dialog for doing this change.
Does anyone know of a workaround or some other feature that could do this? I already have help text over it so it tells you when you hover.

Comment: Then what about calling another function (in which `ui.prompt` is called) inside `onEdit()`? Also, you should first check if the value of the cell is `'No'`.

Comment: Ive tried putting it inside the other function and it still doesnt work. I get an error in the console saying i dont have permission to use the prompt. And i do check, this is just a snippet of what i thought was relevant

Comment: Then what about using 'Protect sheet' with 'range' setting and 'Show a warning when editing this range' permission?

Comment: That is good functionality to learn about, I didn't know about that. But that doesn't quite do it for me. I would need to be able to change the warning message, as well as make it only run when changed to 'No'. I send feedback to see if they'd add that functionality cause I found similar feature requests from people about it.
For now I'm just using an alert that tells the user that the row will be deleted, and to hit Ctrl+z twice if they want the deletion reversed.